# Bash variable expansion variants

Tags: bash

Can someone explan to me the difference between these variable expansion variants?

```
mycommand -datadir=$MN_PATH
```

vs

```
mycommand -datadir="$MN_PATH"
```

vs

```
mycommand -datadir="${MN_PATH}"
```

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe is a more comprehensive reference on expansion syntax.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy Excellent resource!